# Links in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, hyperlink

What is the class type used to create items that look like HTML links in iPhone apps?  Is it just a label with formatted text?  How is the selection detected?

I am looking to have a Navigation Controller and have some text links on the root page.  The user can then select any of the links, and the controller will go to the page for that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIButton and choose "custom" as "type". If you don't specify any border, it looks like click-/tabable text.